# React SynteticEvent provides no blur() method for KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

When I try to use `blur()` method for `target` received from `KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>` I have TypeScript error:

> Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

while same code works perfectly for `target` received from `FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

The origin of this - `KeyboardEvent` target has `EventTarget` type, while `FocusEvent` gives `EventTarget & HTMLInputElement`.

Is this `React.KeyboardEvent` bug or how do I use types properly here without casting via `as`?

[image]

TS issue demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-keyboard-target-issue?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Can you try changing, ```e.target.blur();``` to ```e.currentTarget.blur();``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes current target has correct `EventTarget & HTMLInputElement` type, but  I need `target` here not `currentTarget`

Comment: May I know your exact requirement?? What are you trying to achieve with this input box given??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I need to trigger blur() on `Enter` key pressed, I cant use `<form>` / `ref` / `forwardRef` here. basically the code above works and my question is why `target` has this type - for me it seems like a `React.KeyboardEvent` has bug in type definition, while `React.FocusEvent` is okay